# Прикрепление видео в WYSIWYG редакторе в Django

Tags: django, wysiwyg

Для интеграции WYSIWYG редактора в проект на Django использую библиотеку django-summernote.
Кто пользовался ей, почему при запуске одного и того же проекта на 2-х компьютерах прикрепление видео работает, а на третьем компьютере не прикрепляется видео(даже ошибки не выдает никакой)

Comment: https://github.com/NikolayBaskakov/Bulletin_Board
вот репозиторий с проектом

Comment: "даже ошибки не выдает никакой" - в браузерной консоли смотрели?

Comment: @andreymal в консоли браузеа ничего не выводится. Еще один человек проверил, у негго тоже не прикрепляется. единственное, что я заметил, что на первых двух виндовс 11, а на третьем и четвертом виндовс 10. и вот именно на 10 не прикрепляется